# Android studio unit test for activity

Tags: android, junit4

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TR6QcRozAg for my first time android studio activity unit testing but getting some error in the code where "ActivityTestRule" and "getClass()" showing red colour.Cant run the code

```
package e.asus.supershop;

import android.view.View;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity.class);

    private LoginActivity mActivity = null;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        mActivity = mActivityTestRule.getClass();
    }
    @Test
    public void testLaunch()
    {
        View view = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);
        assertNotNull(view);

    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mActivity = null;
    }
}
```